# Trying to replicate this Chapter Style using titlesec

Tags: lyx, chapters, tikz-styles, titlesec, content-replication

I have created this style for my section titles in Lyx using the option shaded background box and defining the text as "section *"

[image: lyx shaded box]

, this is how it looks in Lyx (the pink color is just the editor, i want to show you how it looks in the editor)

[image]

but I can't use shaded background box for chapters title, then I want to replicate this simple style, but I am a newbie in titlesec, and the styles that I have found in internet are too complex to modify them, please can you help me?

Right now my chapters are looking like this:

[image]

But i would like to make they look exactly like this:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What you want is not  clear. Should  Chapter 1 and the title be on the same line. You seem to have several background colours, and one with a frame. Is it indeed what you want?

Comment: You are right, I will edit the question right now!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose this small code, using titlesec and the `shaded*`  environment, from the `framed` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,]{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{shadecolor} {Gainsboro!60!Lavender}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries}{\begin{shaded*}\filleft 
\Large\chaptername~\thechapter\end{shaded*}}{0ex}{\LARGE}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Marco Teórico}

\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: to have a similar layout dor unnumbered chapters (table of contents, of figures, tables, bibliography); you can use the `numberless key` and  load titlesec with the `explicit` option. Here's a code for the modified relevant part of the preamble:

```
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries}{\begin{shaded*}\filleft \Large\chaptername~ \thechapter\end{shaded*}}{0ex}{\LARGE#1}
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}{\bfseries}{}{0ex}
{\begin{shaded*}\LARGE#1\end{shaded*}}
```

and the result for the table of contents:

[image]

Comment: I had to make some changes due to lyx,but it worked great, except that i have to find how to change also ToC, LoF titles.

Comment: @Ask_Ay:Could you explain exactly what you want for toc and the like, as they are unnumbered chapters?

Comment: just because i want the same style for all my chapters (doesnt matter if they are numbered or not)

Comment: What should have  a grey background then?

Comment: Table of contents, list of figures, list of tables, number chapters, bibliography and Anexos (Appendix)

Comment: For unnumbered chapters, it should be the chapter titles, I suppose?

Comment: Yes, like biblography, anexos, etc

Comment: @Ask_Ay:  I've posted a slightly modifed code for the general case, completed by a `\titleformat` for unnumbered chapters. Please see whether it corresponds to what you want.